# im getting select options from API in that one option should be selected

Tags: php, codeigniter

im getting select options from API in that one option should be selected

```
<select>
<option value= "<?php  echo $value['brand_id'] ;?>" > <?php  echo $value['brand_name'] ;?> </option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
```

one option has value 5 should be selected when we load page

Comment: <option value= "<?php  echo $value['brand_id'] ;?>" > <?php  echo $value['brand_name'] ;?> </option> <?php } ?>

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of writing `<?php echo $var; ?>`, you can use the short syntax `<?= $var ?>` (you can also omit the `;` if the php block only contains one single expression). Imho, it makes the code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:-

```
<option <?php echo ($value['brand_id']==5)?' selected ':''; ?> value= "<?php  echo $value['brand_id'] ;?>" > <?php  echo $value['brand_name'] ;?> </option>
```